# How do you call the operation $\Lambda(X) = \{\alpha\in X| |X\cap\alpha|=\alpha\}$ on the ordinals?

Tags: set-theory

I found this operation $\Lambda(X) = \{\alpha\in X| |X\cap\alpha|=\alpha\}$ with $X\subset On$ in the book "The higher infinite" of Akahiro Kanamori and can't really imagine what it does. So could anyone please tell me how you call this operation (as it seems quite standard) or give me an example?

Comment: Does the source clarify whether the notation $|\cdots|=\alpha$ implies that $\alpha$ must be an _initial_ ordinal? Or does $|\cdot|$ denote order type rather than cardinality here?

Comment: It should be the cardinality here, so yes, $\alpha$ must be an initial ordinal.

Comment: I don't know of a standard terminology, but you may say that $X$ *reflects* at $\alpha$. (Note however, that *reflecting* is used in different ways in set theory, e.g. a stationary set $S$ reflects at $\alpha$ iff $S \cap \alpha$ is stationary.)